# Ускорить загрузку сайта

Tags: php, изображения, обработка-изображений

Здравствуйте. Как лучше организовать хранение фотографий?

Как лучше сохранять изображения от пользователей (аватар, обложка страницы, посты на стене и т.д.). В скольких размерах? Например, миниатюра 60х60, основное фото профиля 200х200, увеличенная версия - 1000х1000. Так? И как тогда это оптимизировать? В скрипте если будет три фото сразу сохраняться, не слишком ли долго будет это происходить?

Comment: Можно ведь кэшировать. Точно знаю, что в Django при использовании sorl - картинки кэшируются при первом рендере страницы.

Comment: Непонятно, о какой скорости идет речь. В начале вопроса вроде бы про показ страниц сайта, а потом аффтар плавно съезжает на загрузку фотографий. мне кажется ему надо определиться, про что он спрашивает

Comment: @Ипатьев Ресайз большой фотографии в миниатюру увеличивает время загрузки страницы. Поэтому я понимаю, что нужно при сохранении фотографии, сохранять её в нескольких размерах. Вот я и спрашиваю, как лучше организовать сохранение миниатюр. Ещё и желательно, чтобы это не занимало много времени.

Comment: Ну вот и надо про это спрашивать, а не растекаться мыслью по древу

Comment: @Ипатьев извиняюсь, если не смог сразу сформулировать нормально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это каталог, то можно организовать lazy load. Плагин на [jquery](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Второй вариант http-кэширование. Детальнее по [нему](http://html5.by/blog/cache/) (так же рекомендую [почитать](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5066793/)).

Ну и делать [тумбы](http://i-novice.net/2-sposoba-sozdaniya-thumbnail-na-php/). А разрешения вы сами подбираете под свой проект.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад помочь :)

Answer (score 4):

Создавайте миниатюры по крону или через очереди. Тогда пользователь не будет ждать. Так же можно создавать миниатюру при первом обращении к ней. Например, если настроить nginx так, что бы на .jpg сначала проверялось наличие статики, а если ее нет, запрос отправлялся на скрипт, который генерит миниатюру и отдает ее в output. При следующем обращении будет отдаваться сразу статика

Comment: Спасибо большое. Не работал ни с кронами, ни с очередями... Придётся гуглить.